# ImageCapture is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, getusermedia

I am trying to execute this code:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

var interval;
var track;

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})
.then(gotMedia)
.catch(err => console.error('getUserMedia() failed: ', err));

function gotMedia(mediastream) {
    track = mediastream.getVideoTracks()[0];
    var imageCapture = new ImageCapture(track);
    interval = setInterval(function () {
      imageCapture.grabFrame()
        .then(processFrame)
        .catch(err => console.error('grabFrame() failed: ', err));
    }, 1000);
}

function processFrame(imgData) {
    canvas.width = imgData.width;
    canvas.height = imgData.height;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(imgData, 0, 0);
}

function stopGrabFrame(e) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    track.stop();
}
```

to take a snapshot of a live video from my webcam but it fails and the console of the browser says the following:

**getUserMedia() failed:  ReferenceError: ImageCapture is not defined at gotMedia**

Do this means that my web browser (Google Chrome) doesn't support ImageCapture? Can I fix it?

Comment: Where do you get `ImageCapture` from? Is it a library you are using?

Comment: Hi @caisah I didn't include it from anywhere. Here is the source: https://www.w3.org/TR/image-capture/#repeated-grabbing-of-a-frame. They don't seem to include anything.

Comment: Right. Have you tried in other borwsers? I didn't find the documentation for it anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ImageCapture](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-image/) specification is not implemented in any browser yet, except [behind a flag](https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-image/blob/gh-pages/implementation-status.md).